# I want to create two identical tokens in ETH and BSC networks and that they would always have the same price

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, bsc

I searched all over the Internet and found nothing. Projects often have tokens in different networks with the same name and all have the same price. How can this be achieved?

I need a solution to this problem. I can't find it on the Internet

Answer (score 0):

Same token name: The [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) standard that's often used for fungible tokens declares function `name()`. When your token contract implements this function, that's the token name.

Same token price is not really relevant to programming, so I won't go into much detail. But generally - arbitrage traders look for the same asset on different networks/platforms and aim to equalize its price (across the different platforms) because they can earn the difference. E.g. they buy XYZ for 900 on one platform and sell for 1000 on another - which moves the price closer to each other on both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

> Projects often have tokens in different networks with the same name and all have the same price. How can this be achieved?

This is not true. If you research carefully enough, you will find out the prices vary.

> I need a solution to this problem. I can't find it on the Internet

There is no technical solution, only trading. It is called arbitrage trading and it is done by market markets.